# SIR Model with NumPy and Plotlib

Tags: python, numpy

for one of my assignments I'm writing a simple SIR model using Runge Kutta-4 on phyton, however, I seem to hit some kind of barrier, as my model always resolves into vertical or horizontal lines, rather than the logistic curves it is supposed to, I couldn't spot the problem help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# definiton of the model


def SIR(x, params):

    alpha = params["alpha"]
    beta = params["beta"]
    
    xdot = np.array([-beta*x[0]*x[1], beta*x[0]*x[1]-alpha*x[2], alpha*x[2]])
  
    return xdot


def RungeKutta4(f, x0, t0, tf, dt):
    t = np.arange(t0, tf, dt)
    nt = t.size

    nx = x0.size

    x = np.zeros((nx, nt))

    x[:, 0] = x0

    for k in range(nt-1):

        k1 = dt*f(t[k], x[:, k])
        k2 = dt*f(t[k]+dt/2, x[:, k]+k1/2)
        k3 = dt*f(t[k]+dt/2, x[:, k]+k2/2)
        k4 = dt*f(t[k]+dt/2, x[:, k]+k3/2)

        dx = (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6

        x[:, k+1] = x[:, k]+dx

        return x, t


params = {"alpha": 0.001 , "beta": 46.48}


def f(t, x): return SIR(x, params)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #This zero was added in order to prevent errors
    x0 = np.array([900, 1, 0])

    t0 = 0
    tf = 10
    dt = 0.0001

    x, t = RungeKutta4(f, x0, t0, tf, dt)

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(t, x[0, :], "r", label="Suceptible")
    plt.plot(t, x[1, :], "g", label="Infected")
    plt.plot(t, x[2, :], "b", label="Recovered")
    plt.xlabel("Time(t)")
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()
```

[the issue of vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3a4w.png)

Comment: Your `k4` formula is wrong, there is no division by 2 there.

Comment: Zooming in finds that with the given parameters the first equilibrium state with `S -> 0` is reached at time `t=0.0004`. The slow fall to the final equilibrium with `I -> 0` happens in scales of `1/alpha = 1000` time units. Thus both processes are not observable with the discretization in the given code.

Comment: Also, the second interaction term should be `alpha*x[1]` for the standard zombie apocalypse model.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is inside your `for loop` so it exits after one step.

Also one more thing is that you are not `normalising by N` (total population) in your model equation, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, ı didn't normalize on purpose to have readout based on the total population. Still the recovered function, do you doesn't seem to work, do you have any clues